# sidewaysfire and twosided

Tags: latex, printing

I try two use sidewaysfigure from the rotating package in the twosided memoir class. The resulting figures look correct in the pdf that is generated, with the page rotated by 90 degrees.

However, when I print the document (on linux, using CUPS), some of the pages with a sidewaysfigure are upside down (rotated by 180 degreeS).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution found:

```
latex junk.tex && dvips -Ppdf -G0 -sPAPERSIZE=a4 junk.dvi && ps2pdf -dAutoRotatePages=/None junk.ps
```

Thanks to http://programming.itags.org/tex/130767/